# Can't remove hidden SASS 3.3.0 gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, sass, rvm

I have installed installed RVM and tried to setup compass - had some errors, so I tried to do it by installing Ruby and then doing everything step by step. THe thing is RVM gems conflict with the ruby gems and whatever I do, even though I Removed .rvm and ran rvm implode and searched for the sas 3.3.0 folder and deleted it manually it still says that ..., because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0) . WHen I do gem list it does not show 3.3.0 , when I try to run compass it's always the same, i'm tired of searching for solutions, but I don't want to reinstall my ubuntu and set everything all up again.

What else could I try to remove that hidden gem from the system? I tried everything I could find - no use at all! There has to be a way to exclude taht dependency to not include 3.3.0 at all!

Maybe installing rvm and creating new gemset would help?

Comment: What version of Compass are you using?

Answer (score 0):

These commands might help you out:

```
# remove all old versions of the gem
gem cleanup rjb

# choose which ones you want to remove
gem uninstall rjb

# remove version 1.1.9 only
gem uninstall rjb --version 1.1.9

# remove all versions less than 1.3.4
gem uninstall rjb --version '<1.3.4'
```

Comment: THank you for your time but the problem is when I use gem uninstall sass it does not list the version which conflicts, it seems hidden, I can remove all sass and the 3.3.0 is still there... Hidden somewhere. I think its due to RVM usage in the past even though its removed now.,

Comment: try using your global rvm. and then remove it might help you out

Comment: as I Stated before rvm is compeltely removed using implode and and some folders deleted manually..